# Javascript Returns NaN if names changed

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to create a cart for my project website in our school. I copied a Javascript syntax and tried changing the names to what I already have in my website. However, doing so returns NaN Value. Can someone please help me out to figure out why? Thank you so much!

Here is the original code:

**javascript:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("input").change (function() {
    var toplam=0;
    $("input[name=gider]").each(function(){
        toplam=toplam + parseInt($(this).val());
    })
    $("input[name=toplam_gider]").val(toplam);
});
```

});

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="gider" value="0"></input><br><br>
<input type="text" name="gider" value="0"></input><br><br>
<input type="text" name="gider" value="0"></input><br><br>
<input type="text" name="toplam_gider" value="0"></input><br><br>
```

Here is my version of the code:

**javascript:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function(e) {
$("input").change (function() {
    var ac
    $("input[name=acf]").each(function(){
        ac=ac + parseInt($(this).val());
    })
    $("input[name=ac_acf]").val(ac);
});
```

});

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="acf" value="0"></input><BR><BR>        
<input type="text" name="acf" value="0"></input><BR><BR>        
<input type="text" name="acf" value="0"></input><BR><BR>        
<input type="text" name="acf" value="0"></input><BR><BR>
<input type="text" name="ac_acf" value="0"></input><BR><BR>
```

I've been trying to replace `"toplam"` with `"ac"` and `"gider"` with `"acf"`
Please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
  var ac = "";
    $("input[name=acf]").each(function(){
        ac=ac + parseInt($(this).val());
    })
    $("input[name=ac_acf]").val(ac);
```

You didn't initialize ac at the beginning